# Image alignment in HTML

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I am stuck on a problem of a aligning a image next to a division in HTML. Below is the code. I want the image to the right of the division but I can't seem to get it.

```
<h1><u><center>                Adolf Hitler </center></u></h1>
<br/>
<div style="height:1000px; width:500px;">
Adolf Hitler (20 April 1889 – 30 April 1945) was an Austrian-born German politician and the leader of the Nazi Party. He was chancellor of Germany from 1933 to 1945 and dictator of Nazi Germany (as Führer und Reichskanzler) from 1934 to 1945. Hitler was at the centre of Nazi Germany, World War II in Europe, and the Holocaust.

Hitler was a decorated veteran of World War I. He joined the German Workers' Party (precursor of the NSDAP) in 1919, and became leader of the NSDAP in 1921. In 1923, he attempted a coup in Munich to seize power. The failed coup resulted in Hitler's imprisonment, during which time he wrote his memoir, Mein Kampf (My Struggle). After his release in 1924, Hitler gained popular support by attacking the Treaty of Versailles and promoting Pan-Germanism, antisemitism, and anti-communism with charismatic oratory and Nazi propaganda. Hitler frequently denounced international capitalism and communism as being part of a Jewish conspiracy.

Hitler's Nazi Party became the largest elected party in the German Reichstag, leading to his appointment as chancellor in 1933. Following fresh elections won by his coalition, the Reichstag passed the Enabling Act, which began the process of transforming the Weimar Republic into the Third Reich, a single-party dictatorship based on the totalitarian and autocratic ideology of National Socialism. Hitler aimed to eliminate Jews from Germany and establish a New Order to counter what he saw as the injustice of the post-World War I international order dominated by Britain and France. His first six years in power resulted in rapid economic recovery from the Great Depression, the denunciation of restrictions imposed on Germany after World War I, and the annexation of territories that were home to millions of ethnic Germans, actions which gave him significant popular support.

Hitler actively sought Lebensraum ("living space") for the German people. His aggressive foreign policy is considered to be the primary cause of the outbreak of World War II in Europe. He directed large-scale rearmament and on 1 September 1939 invaded Poland, resulting in British and French declarations of war on Germany. In June 1941, Hitler ordered an invasion of the Soviet Union. By the end of 1941 German forces and their European allies occupied most of Europe and North Africa. Failure to defeat the Soviets and the entry of the United States into the war forced Germany onto the defensive and it suffered a series of escalating defeats. In the final days of the war, during the Battle of Berlin in 1945, Hitler married his long-time lover, Eva Braun. On 30 April 1945, less than two days later, the two committed suicide to avoid capture by the Red Army, and their corpses were burned. Under Hitler's leadership and racially motivated ideology, the regime was responsible for the genocide of at least 5.5 million Jews, and millions of other victims whom he and his followers deemed racially inferior.</div>
<div>
<img style="margin-bottom:600px; margin-top:0px;" src="/home/vishal/Pictures/hitler_retouched.jpg" align="right"></img>
</div>
```

Comment: Please try to add `float: left; display: inline-block;` both to div and image.

Comment: Put the image before your DIV. http://jsbin.com/qegica/2/edit Also, what kind of tag is `</img>`. You could find a better Lorem Ipsum...

Comment: Nope, it didn't work as I envisioned it, emmanuel.

Comment: also `align` attribute is deprecated, use style `float: (left/right)` instead. Also, don't use inline styles, use a separate stylesheet or wrap your CSS styles into `<style></style>` instead.

Comment: `<center>` element is also deprecated and should not be used. Also, don't use break tags for spacing, that's what margins / padding are for,

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Please refrain from commenting on the content of the source. We try to encourage using the real, actual code in quoted sources on this site, to prevent mismatches between what the OP's problem is and what the quotes show the problem to be. So in this case, replacing the content with lorem ipsum would be counterproductive.

Comment: @VishalSubramanyamRajesh Off topic, but what are you hoping to achieve with the widths and heights in the source? It looks like you not just don't care for responsiveness, but you actively try to prevent the page from looking good on smaller screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this in css file:

```
img
{
float:left;
}
```